# defer or async JavaScript keeps pge from working

Tags: javascript

Google page speed indicates that I should "Remove render-blocking JavaScript"

The problem is if I add defer, async or move the scripts to the bottom of the page the page will display, but nothing will work (pushmenu).

I use 3 scripts.  jQquey and two scripts that are dependent upon jQuery.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Please post sample code.

Comment: Just stop treating Google Page Speed as The Law. Sometimes you need to do things that aren't really fast.

Comment: may be your scripts are out of order.for e.g a script that depends on jquery ,should come after including jquery.Add your code as well in the question.

Comment: Quentin, You are absolutely correct.  The page is fast and displays beautifully without Google's comments.